# UIBarButtonItem getting called only when I swipe

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the BarButtonItem on top of Navigation Bar. And I have assigned a doneMethod for the BarButtonItem. It is not getting detected when I press the button, but If I try to do some swipe on top of the BarButtonItem , it is calling doneMethod. It is really strange for me. Can anyone tell me why ?
[image]

This is the screenshot of my sample app. And in the .h File I have written method as

```
- (IBAction) doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

and respective implementation in .m

```
- (IBAction) doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   NSLog(@"Done Button Pressed");
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Code ? Ok please wait, I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're hooking this up in Interface Builder, so make sure you have used the "Touch Up Inside" event. Sounds like you may have inadvertently used "Touch Drag Inside".

Comment: Ian . I think there is no options for BarButtonItem. Those Touch Down, Touch Up Inside and Touch Drag Inside is meant for UIButtons. Am I Right ? You can easily find that when you try to link the method to buttons. If you try to drag a IBAction method to UIBarButtonItem, it will straight away links with the item.

Comment: Ah, good point. I think you're right. Have you added anything else to the nav bar such as a gesture recognizer?

Comment: No Ian. I am not using gesture as of now. If it is not at all working, I can assume that there is some other problem. But If I do like swipe over barbuttonitem, it is working. This makes me mad.

Comment: I'm not surprised Cyril. I can't think of any reason why this would be happening. Do you have any other code in the .h or .m. It would be useful to see.

Comment: Actually this is working if I create a new demo project. And also It is working in one of my ViewController too, but this wierd behaviour is happening only in this ViewController

Comment: That's why it would be good to see what else is in this class to try and work out why this is happening.

Comment: I am really sorry Ian. The class contains hell lot of code. And I found that somewhere Tapgesture is used which caused this problem. I admit its a poor mistake.